# iOS5 Safari display value for 'datetime' type in forms

Tags: datetime, ios5, mobile-safari

iOS5 Safari now supports `type="datetime"` in form inputs and displays the native iOS datetime picker when a field marked as such is edited.

However, the iOS5 datetime picker does not seem to recognize existing values in these fields -- or, I'm passing a value to it in the wrong format. The format I'm trying is that shown on the picker. The HTML renders as `... type="datetime" value="Nov 17, 2011 5:08 PM" ...`

How do I get iOS5 Safari to recognize preexisting values in these fields and prepopulate the datetime picker when I edit a form with an existing value? Do I need to send a different format?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are having exactly the same problem.

Comment: I did not, I'm afraid. I had to make an kludge of a workaround. (But that's not to say there's no solution... Please post one if you find it.)

Comment: Out of interest what was your workaround? We found that the "date" and "time" versions work with existing values, but the datetime doesn't. We tried dozens of formats and nothing works.

Comment: I use a JavaScript Datetime picker instead. It involves hiding and displaying various fields based on the browser. It ain't pretty, but it works ok and doesn't have to be pretty for this particular application. I wouldn't want to use it in a public production environment, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is **YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD**

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_time_datetime.asp

A correct example is **2012-05-18T00:01:02+03:00**